# update data in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I can't update my data with this code and my data in sqlite not change.

```
var path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + @"\users.sqlite";
var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);

var query = db.Table<User>().Where(c => c.ID == ID_countact_save).SingleOrDefault();
query.Fname = Fname_TB.Text;
query.Lname = Lname_TB.Text;
query.Phone = Phone_TB.Text;
query.Mobile = Mobile_TB.Text;
query.Address = Address_TB.Text;
query.Email = Email_TB.Text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the fields don't automatically update DB
You need to use `Update` method in your `SQLiteConnection` object
that would be like

```
db.Update(query);
```

this is assuming that your `ID` field has   `[PrimaryKey]` attribute
look at this article just for an example of how to do things in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to update, you could do something like this :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Update User_table set Fname='"+Fname_TB.Text+"' where id='"+query.ID+"'";
```